# WebBrowser does not display content properly when using HTTP Basic Auth

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8

I am trying to access a webpage that requires basic authentication using WebBrowser. I know the WebBrowser does not natively support displaying a prompt for basic authentication. However to get around that, I am passing in the username and password in a header or directly in the url.

**Header Method**

```
string hdr = "Authorization: Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("user" + ":" + "passwd")) + System.Environment.NewLine;
GetCurrentWebBrowser().Navigate(new Uri("https://httpbin.org/basic-auth/user/passwd"), null, hdr);
```

**URL Method**

```
UriBuilder uriSite = new UriBuilder("https://httpbin.org/basic-auth/user/passwd");
uriSite.UserName = "user";
uriSite.Password = "passwd";
GetCurrentWebBrowser().Navigate(uriSite.Uri);
```

Using fiddler, I can see that the device is correctly making a request to the webpage when using the methods above. However the WebBrowser does not display the content, fire a navigation failed or a navigation completed event. Does any one know of what could be done to fix this issue or is this a known issue with WebBrowser control on Windows Phone 8?